# Trying to copy a variable-length list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy a list from Sheet A to sheet B. (I have the number of rows used by the data in the list saved in a cell, if needed.)

The spreadsheet file contains 5 sheets, of which "Analysis" is one. It contains 4-5 tables, each separated by a blank row.

The list itself is variable in length - sometimes it's 9 rows, sometimes its 17. Thankfully, it's always 5 columns wide.

Once I get the list into Sheet B, I need to set all cell borders to TRUE.

Here's the code that I've been playing with:

```
var sss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById(Sheet A);
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Analysis'); // 

var tblRows = sss.getRange('Analysis!K190').getValue();
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getRange('190,5,tblRows,5'); //assign the range you want to copy
var data = range.getValues();

var tss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById(Sheet B);
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('2018');
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,tblrows,5).setValues(data);
```

(I'm not sure that this formatted properly)

Anyhow, I have the number of rows used by the list saved as a variable in a spreadsheet cell, and I'd like to use that, because I have found "getLastRow" to get the last row of the sheet, not the last row that is non-blank. (It might be giving me trouble because I'm doing something wrong, tho...) I know that I've messed up, so feel free to throw everything out and start over, if needed.

Anybody care to throw some ideas my way?

Comment: Regarding getLastRow, you are confusing it with [getMaxRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows). 

From [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow): `Returns the position of the last row` that has content.

Comment: The question is unclear as it doesn't include enough details. Add a brief description of the sheet structure. How many tables are included on it?

Comment: It seems that there are a lot of things that I don't know about GAS. "getMaxRows" is one of those things. I've always used "getLastRow", but I've never been able to get the row amount correct. That's why I turned to SO.

Comment: In answer to another question, I'm using Sheets to double-check my paycheck. The spreadsheet file contains 5 sheets, of which "Analysis" is one. It contains 4-5 tables, each separated by a blank row. I need to copy the contents of one of those tables to a different sheet. Unfortunately, the contents of that table varies in length (rows). Sometimes it's 14 rows, sometimes 19, then 16, etc...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details to it.

Comment: Ruben, what details are you referring to? I need to copy a table from spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B. The source table has a statc start point, variable number of rows, and is always 4 columns wide.

Comment: I would love to simply share my spreadsheet file, but I can't due to privacy reasons.

Comment: Ruben, will any of the other "tables" in the Analysis sheet affect the code acting against the table that needs to be copied?

Comment: Ruben, a related question - my script has at least 6 separate and distinct actions. Each "action" is performed by several lines of code. Will unrelated code affect the code copying the table in question?